# How to extract individual variable from a given dataset?

Tags: julia, feature-extraction, feature-engineering

I would like to inquire about extracting data from a given dataset (I guess it is  similar to data decomposition).
The goal is to decompose a dataset to extract the features?

**For example:** Extract individual components of the `volume` of `rectangle prism` without the knowledge of the `individual features` (length, width, height).

Please do recommend best practice to carry out the operation. Also, do suggest any book or article which can explain such process in detail?

### Update

The example code for the analysis:

```
using DataFrames
mutable struct rect
    length
    breadth
    height
end
r = rect(rand(Int, 40), rand(Int, 40), rand(Int, 40))
volume(rect) = rect.length .* rect.breadth .* rect.height
volume_val = volume(r)
df = DataFrame(:length => r.length, :width=> r.width, :height=> r.height, :volume => volume_val)

# For this df dataframe, I would like to extract length, width and height from volume without the use of volume equation
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean searching for which values of length, width, height you get the given volume?

```
using DataFrames
mutable struct rect
    length
    width
    height
end
r = rect(rand(1:100, 10), rand(1:100, 10), rand(1:100, 10))
volume(rect) = rect.length .* rect.width .* rect.height
volume_val = volume(r)

julia> df = DataFrame(:length => r.length, :width=> r.width, :height=> r.height, :volume => volume_val)
10×4 DataFrame
 Row │ length  width  height  volume
     │ Int64   Int64  Int64   Int64
─────┼───────────────────────────────
   1 │     41     82      58  194996
   2 │     41     57      92  215004
   3 │     88     42      63  232848
   4 │     32     98      12   37632
   5 │     26     65      14   23660
   6 │     94     26      40   97760
   7 │     14     72      65   65520
   8 │     51     72      79  290088
   9 │     36     50      26   46800
  10 │     63     22      94  130284

julia> df[df.volume .== 46800,:]
1×4 DataFrame
 Row │ length  width  height  volume
     │ Int64   Int64  Int64   Int64
─────┼───────────────────────────────
   1 │     36     50      26   46800
```

Comment: thanks for the feedback!! 
My question is more towards extracting `length`, `width` and `height` (features) without knowing their values from `volume` column.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you're trying to do

Comment: sorry for late reply! 
Explanation for the question, For a rectangular prism, by default there should be three components like length, width and height. But what if the height is missing!, then how can I estimate a suitable vector for height variable maybe lets say using statistical approach or even any mathematical modelling? haha

Comment: let me try to rephrase it to see if I understand. With one of `length|width|height|volume`  missing (and only one), you want to find the missing value. Are you supposed to know that `length*width*height=volume` ?

Comment: thanks for the response! 
No one should not be aware of `length*width*height=volume`.

Comment: I just created this dataset randomly, what if there is some other similar datasets with not full features, how would one estimate the missing feature?

Comment: there is probably no easy solution to your problem. You can try a linear/quadratic/etc regression, or even training a artificial neural network